# One ViewController with two segues triggered by an If statement

Tags: swift

I am trying to have two segues which are triggered by If statements. Here is the coding I have so far.

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, AnyObject?) {

```
    if segue.identifier == "SomeoneWon" {

            var ThirdVC: WinnerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WinnerViewController

            ThirdVC.WinnerName = Winner}

    else if segue.identifier == "PopUp" {

            var PopUpVC: PopUpViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PopUpViewController

            PopUpVC.RoundWinnerPop = RoundWinner}
```

The If statements are as follows:

```
         if firstrandomnumber > secondrandomnumber && firstrandomnumber >    thirdrandomnumber && firstrandomnumber > fourthrandomnumber {
        Player1ScoreTotal += 1
        self.Player1Score.text = String(Player1ScoreTotal)
        Winner = receivedString1
        RoundWinner = receivedString1

        if Player1ScoreTotal == 5{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("SomeoneWon", sender: UIButton())}

        else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("PopUp", sender: UIButton())   }}






    else if secondrandomnumber > firstrandomnumber && secondrandomnumber > thirdrandomnumber && secondrandomnumber > fourthrandomnumber {
        Player2ScoreTotal += 1
        self.Player2Score.text = String(Player2ScoreTotal)
        Winner = receivedString2
        RoundWinner = receivedString2

        if Player2ScoreTotal == 5{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("SomeoneWon", sender: UIButton())}

        else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("PopUp", sender: UIButton())}}






    else if thirdrandomnumber > firstrandomnumber && thirdrandomnumber > secondrandomnumber && thirdrandomnumber > fourthrandomnumber {
        Player3ScoreTotal += 1
        self.Player3Score.text = String(Player3ScoreTotal)
        Winner = receivedString3
        RoundWinner = receivedString3

        if Player3ScoreTotal == 5{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("SomeoneWon", sender: UIButton())}

        else{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("PopUp", sender: UIButton())}}









    else if fourthrandomnumber > firstrandomnumber && fourthrandomnumber > secondrandomnumber && fourthrandomnumber > thirdrandomnumber {
        Player4ScoreTotal += 1
        self.Player4Score.text = String(Player4ScoreTotal)
        Winner = receivedString4
        RoundWinner = receivedString4


        if Player4ScoreTotal == 5{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("SomeoneWon", sender: UIButton())
            }

        else{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("PopUp", sender: UIButton())}}
}
```

The segue works but the information for the variables does not get transferred i.e. the label which is suppose to show the values for "Winner" and "RoundWinner" remain blank. I am new so I hope the mistake is simple. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question? Which part is not working?

Comment: I have the variables "Winner" and "RoundWinner" on the respective viewcontrolllers I am trying to segue to. The segues work but the information is not sent i.e. the label who is suppose to display the value for the variables is left blank.

Comment: Why are you using UIButton instead of self in your segue? I don't see that you passing the value in your if statements in the segue. If you add a break point at ThirdVc.WinnerName what is the value for Winner? Have you tried adding a println(Winner) to see what the value is?

Comment: The If statements are in a long line of actions triggered by an initial button press. I changed them to self and they still work fine but do not help the situation. My logic for the if statement was, for example, if the first random number was greater than the others, then player ones score was increased, then displayed, the variables were defined, and then the segue was performed which should carry them over based on the prepareforsegue. @MwcsMac